# Todo/Punchlist for Admins?

Tags: untagged

Does anybody know of a good solution for making a punch/todo list?  I do some desktop support for a moderately sized office.  However, I've tried setting up a support ticket system, but it's a bit overkill.  Any ideas on (windows-based) software that will let me make a simple punch list and easily re-prioritze it?  I've tried using Outlook's Tasks but I've frankly never liked them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider setting up a ticket system, or use a hosted one.  There is some advantage you get to having a history, integrated wiki for network documentation, and other features that you won't get out of a personal task manager.

I really like using [Toodledo](http://www.toodledo.com/) for managing my personal todo list.

- There is a Firefox extension
- iPhone Application
- I can create todo items by sending or forwarding an email
- It can integrate with your Google Calendar
- You can submit via IM
- The system has folders, contexts so you can keep multiple todo lists
- Has levels of priorities that are easily changed.  You can set due-dates for a task, and when an item is past due the priority is automatically increased.

Answer (score 1):

[ToDoList](http://www.abstractspoon.com/). Multi-user capable, XML storage format (making it possible to do reporting), hierarchical tasks, lots of fields, customizable UI, very usable with only a keyboard, and actively developed.

Oh, it's free and open source too.

I've been using it for years, it's basically awesome. That and KeePass are two indispensable tools at my company.